# MYSQL - update a table from another with composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql-update, composite-primary-key

I have an unusual situation where I have to update a table with the values from another, the two tables are identical.

```
Table 1 and Table 2
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| timeStamp   | datetime | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| obj_id      | int(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| value       | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And I need to update table1 with the values stored in table2.

I've tried with some useful piece of information found here on SO...

after several try i've come up with a query of this sort:

```
UPDATE table1 AS f  
    SET table1.value = t.value 
FROM table2 AS t 
WHERE (f.timeStamp, f.obj_id) = (t.timeStamp,t.obj_id);
```

ofc with no luck till now :(

the error is the most common one:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table2 AS t WHERE (f.timeStamp, f.obj_id) = (t.timeStamp,t.obj_id)' at line 1

Comment: This isn't unusual. This is basically replication. However, you cannot simply make up syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first write a SELECT statement, that shows the existing values to be replaced, along with the new values. This lets me test expressions, and visually verify the results e.g.

```
 SELECT t.obj_id
      , t.timestamp 
      , t.value      AS old_value
      , s.value      AS new_value
   FROM table1 s
   JOIN table2 t 
     ON t.timestamp = s.timestamp
    AND t.obj_id    = s.obj_id
  WHERE NOT ( t.value <=> s.value )
```

(I typically use `t` as the alias for the table that is going to be the "target" of the update, and use `s` as the alias for the "source".)

Then I convert that it into an UPDATE statement by replacing  "`SELECT ... FROM`" with the "`UPDATE`" keyword, and adding a "`SET`" clause before the "`WHERE`" clause

```
 UPDATE table1 s
   JOIN table2 t 
     ON t.timestamp = s.timestamp
    AND t.obj_id    = s.obj_id
    SET t.value = s.value
  WHERE NOT ( t.value <=> s.value )
```

Comment: I like the way your code is giving a sense of control by selecting the data to be updated before the actual UPDATE statement, also thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Deiv: That's just the approach I use. I'm not clever enough to write a multi-table update without writing it as a SELECT first. I like to confirm the conditions, and the values... gives me an opportunity to check the results, before I run an UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) for the UPDATE statement, especially the multiple table syntax.

```
UPDATE table1 f 
JOIN table2 t
    ON f.timeStamp = t.timestamp AND f.obj_id = t.obj_id
    SET f.value = t.value;
```